# solving pde by matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

Can you help me please?

I need to solve wave equation using Matlab.
How to solve this PDE by Matlab?

$u_{tt}=c^{2}u_{xx} $ for $0<x<l$

B.C: $u_x(0,t)=0$; $u(l,t)=0$

I.C: $u(x,0)=f(x); u_t(x,0)=-cf'(x)$

Thanks!

Comment: MATLAB has not any software so that it can solve PDE. So we can only solve any PDE manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB could NOT solve this kind of PDEs *analytically*, but MATLAB could solve them *numerically*.

You need to formulate a numerical scheme to solve this equation in MATLAB numerically, either [finite difference method](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/fd1d_wave/fd1d_wave.html), or [finite element](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~larisa/www/FEMWaveEq.pdf)(same with FDM in 1D), is OK. There are lots of MATLAB scripts for solving 1D wave equation already out there on the internet, for example, [this](http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/matlab.html).

Also, MATLAB has a [PDE tool box](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/pde/ug/bqivxzv-1.html) that could handle wave equation, you could launch the GUI of PDE tool box from the start menu of MATLAB, for a step-by-step instruction please see the link above.